# How to complete a task in two seperate 'else' statements while maintaining DRY

Tags: design-patterns, python

What is the best way to implement the following code without having the same code duplicated in two different blocks, but while maintaining efficiency and readability?

```
if (expression1):
    if (expression2 that can only be checked if expression1):
        doSomething()
    else:
        doSomethingElse()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( expression1 and expression2):
 doSomething()
else:
 doSomethingElse()
```

Since Python supports [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting), Expression2 will only be evaluated if expression1 is true.

Comment: I am aware that this is the case but this I'm pretty sure that this behaviour isn't guaranteed by the spec and explicit is better than implicit, right? I think this hampers readability.

Comment: It is a faily common idiom in some languages to use short-circuit evaluation this way. Eg. - The first expression will be to check a pointer is not null, and dereference the pointer in the second expression.

Comment: But as I am not a python programmer, I will let someone else answer whether this would be idiomatic python or not...

Comment: it is explicitely stated in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: Thank you @Newtopian, I was not aware that this was guaranteed. It still doesn't totally sit right with me but I think that's grounds for this to be the accepted answer. Thanks all!

Comment: I understand your concern to be as explicit as possible, that said, short circuiting like this is fairly common in many languages.  Perhaps a quick comment in the else with a link to the docs would provide some comfort.

Comment: @Newtopian That's a good idea. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I like the AND answer, but you could also use early return.

```
if exp1 :
    if exp2 :
        doSomething()
        return

doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: This worries me because it's easy to miss the return statement and assume that the doSomethingElse() will always be executed while skim-reading the code. Returning is not possible if more code need be executed after this block.

Comment: yes, thats why people prefer the AND solution and functions

Comment: .. and languages with {}

Comment: @Ewan I don't get how braces can make the `return` more visible. If it's easy to miss there, it's easy to miss with braces too.